# Was Clara's "I love you" directed at the Doctor?

Tags: doctor-who

At the end of Series 8 Episode 8, "Mummy on the Orient Express", Clara is talking to her boyfriend Danny on the phone while she's in the TARDIS with the Doctor:

> DANNY: So, is it done?
>   CLARA: Yep. Mission accomplished. Listen, I can't talk now but I'll see you soon and, er, I love you.
>   DANNY: I love you, too.

One of the comments to the above Youtube video says:

> Jenna Coleman confirmed in an interview that Clara's "I love you" in this scene was really directed toward The Doctor. This is one of the best episodes of the whole show.﻿

Now of course I know better than to take Youtube comments for granted, but I've found the same claim repeated on Jenna Coleman's [TV Tropes](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Creator/JennaColeman?from=Creator.JennaLouiseColeman) page - still without a citation to a primary source.

**Did Jenna Coleman actually say this? If so, when and where?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the person is referring to an interview Jenna did in which she she was asked who Clara was saying "I love you" to. Her response is, "The Doctor."

Link to the video:

(at around 2:09)

Comment: Wow. After 2 years, you found the exact quote I was looking for! Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I think the person who left the comment misunderstood her point in the interview. If it's the same one I found (with the [Sydney Morning Herald](http://www.smh.com.au/entertainment/tv-and-radio/between-the-time-lines-clara-is-in-love-with-doctor-who-20150914-gjm2l7.html)), here's her full response:

> **Q:** Did you just say they love each other? Is Clara in love with
>   the Doctor?
>
> **Coleman:** "She's totally in love with him, always has been."
>
> **Q:** What does that mean?
>
> **Coleman:** "It's its own kind of love. He is her
>   hero, but she would be very reluctant to tell him that. It's a
>   doctor-and-companion love, and there's nothing else like it, really.
>   The relationship is: he is her father, he is her alien best friend, he
>   is her annoying child sometimes that has, like, no social skills. It's
>   kind of an unquantifiable love, I think."

Of course, I have no idea if this is the interview they're referring to or not, but as you can see Jenny Coleman definitely believed their relationship to be more of a father/daughter, friendship kind of love.

That being said, she also hints (a few questions above this one) that the previous doctor (Matt Smith) had potential as a romantic interest. The quote above is referring to Capaldi.